# Django How to Filter Model Instances and also Related Objects for Each Instance. Nested Filtering?

Tags: python, django

I have three models, Genre, Movie and Review. Each genre can have multiple movies, and each movie can have multiple reviews. I have been trying to filter the related objects of a Genre instance such that the queryset contains only active movies, and each of those active movies contains only active reviews.

**models.py**

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160)


class Movie(models.Model):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='movies')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Review(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

How can I obtain a queryset from a Genre instance which contains only active movies and reviews? Thank you for your time!

**edit:**
My goal is to use this queryset to retrieve each active movie, and then for each active movie, retrieve each active review. So, I am looking for a solution that gives a queryset which can easily be iterated in the order of active movies first, and then active reviews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Review.objects.filter(active=True, movie__active=True, movie__genre=genre1)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "through" relations.

If you want to retrieve `Movie`s and only the active reviews, we can work with a `Prefetch` object:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Movie.objects.filter(active=True, genre=genre1).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'reviews',
        queryset=Review.objects.filter(active=True),
        to_attr='active_reviews'
    )
)
```

the `Movie`s that arise from this queryset will have an attribute `.active_review`s that contains only reviews that are active.